# How would I go about urls that need to have special characters?

Tags: php, mysql, get, special-characters

So originally I had the issue of certain pages not loading because the url had special characters like ', !, etc, but the url is created from the folder name. In case of a user uploading a folder with special characters that Need to be displayed when echo'd, how can I remove it from the folder but keep it when the links are displayed? I was thinking that maybe Instead of giving the user a chance to name the folder and it be created directly with mkdir, I would upload the folder name that they chose to a database and create a folder with just an incrementing value. I don't know if that is a good Idea though or if the code I have written is even any good so I was hoping you guys could give me some advice and maybe a solution?

```
<?php 
# Get Variables
$seriesGet = $_GET['series'] ?? "";
$chapterGet = $_GET['chapter'] ?? "";


$seriesDir = scandir("series/");

print_r($seriesDir);


echo "<br>";

# Display Series folders

if (!$_GET) {
    $arrayStart = 0;

    foreach ($seriesDir as $series => $value) {
        if ($seriesDir[$arrayStart] != "." && $seriesDir[$arrayStart] != "..") {
            echo "<a href='testScript.php?series=". $seriesDir[$arrayStart] ."'>". $seriesDir[$arrayStart] ."</a>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $arrayStart = $arrayStart + 1;
    }
}
echo "<br>";

# Display chapters in series folder

if ($seriesGet && !$chapterGet) {

    $chapterDir = scandir("series/" . $seriesGet . "/");
    $seriesPath = "series/$seriesGet";

    echo "<img src='$seriesPath/cover.jpg'>";
    readfile("$seriesPath/description.txt");

    echo "<br>";
    $array2Start = 0;
    foreach ($chapterDir as $series => $value) {
        if ($chapterDir[$array2Start] != "." && $chapterDir[$array2Start] != ".." && $chapterDir[$array2Start] != "cover.jpg" && $chapterDir[$array2Start] != "description.txt") {
            echo "<a href='testScript.php?series=". $seriesGet . "&chapter=" . $chapterDir[$array2Start] ."'>". $chapterDir[$array2Start] ."</a>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $array2Start = $array2Start + 1;
    }
}

# Display Images

if ($seriesGet && $chapterGet) {
    $dirname = "series/" . $seriesGet. "/" . $chapterGet . "/";

    print_r($dirname);

    $images = glob($dirname."*.{jpg,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To encode reserved entities (special characters) in a URL, you use [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

For example, a exclamation point `!` becomes encoded as `%21`.  For the characters you mention, you can consult an ASCII table to see what the value should be.

> I was thinking that maybe Instead of giving the user a chance to name the folder and it be created directly with mkdir, I would upload the folder name that they chose to a database and create a folder with just an incrementing value.

Yes, you should never let your users choose the name of the file on disk.  There are a whole range of attacks that are possible if you do this and are not extremely careful.  The most common cases are where the user uploads executable content, or uses relative paths to write to other locations.  For example, they might upload `something-evil.php`, and perhaps your web server is misconfigured and actually runs their code when going to `https://example.com/uploads/something-evil.php`.  Or, maybe they upload like `../../../../etc/init.d/evil-script` and it runs on your server.

It's easier to avoid the problem entirely by not allowing the user control over the filename, like you're proposing.  Just make sure they can't overwrite other files, or name the files at all, even if they are in another folder.

Now, let's review your code...

```
$chapterDir = scandir("series/" . $seriesGet . "/");
```

This is dangerous!  The user is specifying what path to read.  Like I said above, you're actually allowing them to insert relative paths and read whatever PHP can read.  Misconfigured web servers are very common, and you don't want them reading stuff from storage that they're not supposed to read.

```
echo "<a href='testScript.php?series=". $seriesDir[$arrayStart] ."'>"...
```

Never concatenate arbitrary data into the context of HTML!  There are actual multiple problems here.  The first is that you must URL-encode anything used in the URL.  Use `urlencode()`.  The next is that your data isn't escaped for HTML, so some data could leak in some script tags or something, or even just make your HTML invalid.  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data you inject into HTML, even if its your own trusted data.  You're moving data from one context to the other and it needs to be escaped properly.

I strongly recommend reading the OWASP Top 10:  https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

Comment: I will definitely deal with everything you pointed out, for the first half I wasnt worried about that because it will only be website admins adding folders to the website, but i should fix it jut incase. As for the second part of what you said about my code, I totally understand what your saying and didnt even think about that. But i am not sure how to implement the urlencode() or htmlspecialchars() to the echo'd link without making it lead to the urls being unable to be identified. perhaps this whole method is just bad practice and i need to think of another method to get each series/chapter?

Comment: @Thatguy553 Special characters in the URL have to be encoded to be sent to the server anyway.  They're decoded on the server end.  The reserved HTML entities are decoded by the browser as the HTML is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

A great filename convention would do you good in the future. Don't give too much freedom to users, you can also follow the naming convention of Window's computers when naming files and folders.

See this link:

https://libguides.princeton.edu/c.php?g=102546&p=930626